# How I Add Button Go To The Instagram?

Tags: ios, xcode

how r u ?

can you help me

please how i add button in my app he go to instagram app and display my account page ?

like this :

[image]

please Help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for (not entirely sure since your question wasn't very descriptive).

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://user?username=USERNAME"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] url]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] url];
} else {
// handle the issue
}
```

Otherwise, see the instagram api [here](http://instagram.com/developer/).